# local "merge" in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, database, merge, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering if there's a way to merge new mappings with database data, such as with `session.merge`, but without updating the database? Like when I do a `pull` with git, to get a local state which is a merge of the remote and previous local state(which might contain unpushed commits), but without updating the remote state. Here, I want to get a local "view" of the state that would result from doing a `session.merge`.

Maybe making savepoint(with `session.begin_nested`), then doing a `session.merge` and later on a `session.rollback` would accomplish this, but is there a way that doesn't require this kind of transaction management(which can imply actual undo operations on the db, so not terribly efficient for my purposes)?

Would using `session.no_autoflush` do the trick?

Example code for what I want to do:

```
local_merge = session.merge_local(Model(...))
# do stuff with local_merge...
remotes = session.query(Model).all()
# remotes should remain "old" db versions, as no data was pushed
return something
```

Edit: So I think I may be wrong on the `rollback` method being inefficient. At least, as long as no `commit` are emitted, there shouldn't be expensive undo operations, only chucking out the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge will only update the database because of the auto-flush. You can turn that off temporarily using the `session.no_autoflush` context manager, or just setting `autoflush=False` on your session. You can also pass `autoflush=False` to your `sessionmaker`.

One thing to watch out for is how the results of the `session.query(Model).all()` will interact with the unflushed, changed, local objects.

Because the `session` maintains a record of unique objects (against primary keys) in an Identity Map, you will not be able to have two versions of the same object in the same session.

Here's an example which shows how local changes interact with `autoflush=False`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s')>" % self.name


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

ed_user = User(name='ed')
session.add(ed_user)
session.commit()

ed_again = session.query(User).get(1)
ed_again.name = "not ed"

with session.no_autoflush:
    ed_three = session.query(User).get(1)
    all_eds = session.query(User).all()
    print(ed_again, id(ed_again))
    print(ed_three, id(ed_three))
    print(all_eds, id(all_eds[0]))

<User(name='not ed')> 139664151068624
<User(name='not ed')> 139664151068624
[<User(name='not ed')>] 139664151068624
```

Yep, it's not able to get the original Ed from the database, even with `no_autoflush` - this is to be expected for `get()`, since it will check the identity map first before the database, and won't bother querying the DB if it finds it in the identity map. But with `query.all()`, it queries the database, finds that one of the objects it gets back was already in the identity map, and returns that reference instead so as to maintain uniqueness of objects in the `session` (which was also my hunch, but I couldn't find this explicitly spelled out in the docs).

You could do something like [expunge](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#expunging) objects from a `session`, but I think the easiest way to have an old and new copy of the merged objects is to use two separate sessions, one where the changes will be merged and possibly committed and one which you can use to check the existing state of objects in the database.

Comment: Hmm, cool. That makes sense, and that's the behavior I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was confused on whether doing a query would force a flush, or otherwise not expose the right version of the data.